# Query to find combinations of accounts sql

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am looking for how to form a query, where I seek to find that the ordering accounts are interacting with the same beneficiary accounts 3 or more times. As I describe below.
**Examples:**
Account **A** sends account 1,2,and 3.
Account **B** sends account 1,2 and 3.
Account **C** sends account 1,2 and 3.

This is the table called TBL_ACCOUNTS

| ordering account | beneficiary account |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 3 |
| C | 3 |
| H | 1 |
| K | 23 |
| Z | 329 |
| W | 3 |

I want to find all those accounts that meet this condition, that the ordering accounts are interacting with the same beneficiary accounts 3 or more times. The result you would expect to get is.

| ordering account | beneficiary account |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 2 |
| C | 3 |

I hope you can guide me which way to go, because I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Please  post a [mcve] with the table definition (DDL), and the sample data and expected output in a TABLE format. This is too hard to decipher otherwise.

Comment: If you add more detail, with their respective fields and values ​​in the table. I hope you can guide me how I can form the query.

Comment: You want to show all rows from all accounts for which exists another account with at least three benificiaries in common? So if we add account D with 1,2,3,4,5,6 and account E with 4,5,6,7,8,9, then you would want to show all these rows, because D shares 1,2,3 with A, B, and C, and E shares 4,5,6 with D. Correct?

Comment: If there was a `C, 4` row would you want to include it, since `C` has 3 matches with `A` and `B`, or exclude it, since there is no `A, 4` or `B, 4` rows?

Comment: Exactly, it would have to show only those that they have in common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a collection data type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE int_list IS TABLE OF INT;
```

and then you can use:

```sql
WITH accounts (ordering_account, beneficiary_account, accounts) AS (
  SELECT t.*,
         CAST(
           COLLECT(beneficiary_account) OVER (PARTITION BY ordering_account)
           AS int_list
         )
  FROM   TBL_ACCOUNTS t
)
SELECT ordering_account,
       beneficiary_account
FROM   accounts a
WHERE  EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   accounts x
         WHERE  a.ordering_account <> x.ordering_account
         AND    CARDINALITY(a.accounts MULTISET INTERSECT x.accounts) >= 3
         -- Remove the next line if you want to return all accounts and not just the matched accounts
         AND    a.beneficiary_account = x.beneficiary_account
       );
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TBL_ACCOUNTS (ordering_account, beneficiary_account) AS
SELECT 'A',   1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B',   1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'C',   1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A',   2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B',   2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C',   2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A',   3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B',   3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C',   3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C',   4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'H',   1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'K',  23 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Z', 329 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'W',   3 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ORDERING_ACCOUNT | BENEFICIARY_ACCOUNT |
> | --- | --- |
> | A | 1 |
> | A | 3 |
> | A | 2 |
> | B | 1 |
> | B | 3 |
> | B | 2 |
> | C | 1 |
> | C | 2 |
> | C | 3 |

---

If you want to do it without a collection then:

```sql
SELECT ordering_account,
       beneficiary_account
FROM   TBL_ACCOUNTS a
WHERE  EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   TBL_ACCOUNTS x
         WHERE  a.ordering_account <> x.ordering_account
         AND    a.beneficiary_account = x.beneficiary_account
         AND    EXISTS(
                  SELECT 1
                  FROM   TBL_ACCOUNTS l
                         INNER JOIN TBL_ACCOUNTS r
                         ON (l.beneficiary_account = r.beneficiary_account)
                  WHERE  l.ordering_account = a.ordering_account
                  AND    r.ordering_account = x.ordering_account
                  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
                )
       );
```

or:

```sql
SELECT ordering_account,
       beneficiary_account
FROM   TBL_ACCOUNTS a
WHERE  EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   TBL_ACCOUNTS l
                INNER JOIN TBL_ACCOUNTS r
                ON (   l.beneficiary_account = r.beneficiary_account
                   AND l.ordering_account <> r.ordering_account )
         WHERE  l.ordering_account = a.ordering_account
         GROUP BY r.ordering_account
         HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
         AND    COUNT(
                  CASE WHEN r.beneficiary_account = a.beneficiary_account THEN 1 END
                ) > 0
       );
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=eba79d766af6f1ede610a481924a29e8)*

Comment: It seems that if it works, and without occupying your collection data and pointing to my tables, which lines are deleted?

Comment: @Salvador The lines that are not shown are `H, 1`, `K, 23`, `Z, 329`, `W, 3` and `C, 4` (but if you remove the penultimate line from the query then `C, 4` will be shown).

Comment: if the results are correct, but I mean that if I don't want to use your example collection data int_list, which lines of the query should be deleted, it is that I had never used collection data like this.

Comment: @Salvador If you don't want to create a collection then you need to find another built-in collection that you can use in its place; for example, you can use something like `SYS.ORA_MINING_NUMBER_NT` instead of `int_list`. If you don't want to use a collection at all then this answer will not work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
select ordering_account, beneficiary
from TBL_ACCOUNTS 
group by ordering_account, beneficiary
having count(*) >= 3
order by ordering_account, beneficiary
```

Comment: No. All ordering_account / beneficiary tuples appear only once in the table shown, so your result set will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T.ordering_account,T.beneficiary_account 
FROM TBL_ACCOUNTS T
JOIN
(
   SELECT Z.ordering_account
   FROM TBL_ACCOUNTS Z
   GROUP BY Z.ordering_account
   HAVING COUNT(*)>2
)X ON T.ordering_account=X.ordering_account
ORDER BY T.ordering_account,T.beneficiary_account
```

or

```
SELECT X.ordering_account,X.beneficiary_account FROM
(
  SELECT T.ordering_account,T.beneficiary_account,
   COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY  T.ordering_account)XCOL
   FROM TBL_ACCOUNTS T
)X WHERE X.XCOL=3
ORDER BY X.ordering_account,X.beneficiary_account
```

Comment: If there is an extra `C, 4` row then the first query gets an extra row and the second query then does not return any `C` rows [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8d86ff4329768f2b6df6c76b1278d6f5)

Comment: Part of it worked, what must be fulfilled is that you must combine what account A sent to account 1,2 and 3 but also account B sent to the same accounts 1,2 and 3. And in these cases paint these records.

Answer (score 0):

Self-join the table on the beneficiary account. Thus you get all ordering account pairs as often as they share the share3 beneficiary accounts. This means you can group by these pairs then and count.

The following query lists all entries of all ordering accounts for which exists another ordering account sharing at least three beneficiary accounts.

```
with share3 as
(
  select a1.ordering_account as acc1, a2.ordering_account as acc2
  from tbl_accounts a1
  join tbl_accounts a2 on a2.beneficiary_account = a1.beneficiary_account
                       and a2.ordering_account > a1.ordering_account
  group by a1.ordering_account, a2.ordering_account
  having count(*) >= 3
)
select *
from tbl_accounts
where exists
(
  select null
  from share3
  where share3.acc1 = tbl_accounts.ordering_account
     or share3.acc2 = tbl_accounts.ordering_account
)
order by ordering_account, beneficiary_account;
```

Comment: Part of it worked, what must be fulfilled is that you must combine what account A sent to account 1,2 and 3 but also account B sent to the same accounts 1,2 and 3. And in these cases paint these records.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I follow what you're asking, but it sounds like you simply need to include an ORDER BY clause.

At the end of your query just include

```
ORDER BY 'ordering account', 'beneficiary account'
```

The only thing that could change this is if you use different kinds of SQL that don't like single quotes. You may need to use [],"", or ``.

Comment: I am not looking to order them, I want to bring only those ordering accounts that are interacting 3 times or more with the same beneficiary accounts, than other ordering accounts, as in the examples I mentioned.

Comment: About every DBMS likes single quotes :-) They mark string literals. What you are ordering by are two string constants, so your results don't get sorted at all.

Comment: I still don't know if I follow what you need, but if you look into APPLY it may get you closer to what you need.